# setter does not recognize ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, getter-setter

im trying to do a banck acc in python with getters and setters but the setter does not recognize the ValueError when I put str in saldo, however it is supposed to popup some error because this is just for int and float not for str

```
class Conta(Cliente):
    def __init__(self, nome, idade, cpf, agencia, conta, saldo):
        super().__init__(nome, idade, cpf)
        self._agencia = agencia
        self._conta = conta
        self.saldo = saldo
 
    @property
    def saldo(self):
        print('teste getter')
        return self._saldo
 
    @saldo.setter
    def saldo(self, value):
        print('test setter')
        if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
            ValueError('value NEED to be a number!')
 
        self._saldo = value
 
cliente = Conta('leonardo', 1231,123123,1232,123123,saldo = 'it is supposed to print ValueError')

#output
test setter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the **`raise`** keyword before the name of the `Exception` to actually raise it, try the following code instead :

```
if not isinstance(value, (int, float)):
    raise ValueError('value NEED to be a number!')
```

Relevant Python documentation page: [Errors and Exceptions - Raising Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions)